# How configurable product price works in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, configurable-product, price

As I understand, magento2 uses configurable product price for showing on front end (ie listing or product detail page) only. It does not carry the configurable product price to cart or checkout. We can not use configurable product price to sell the product because it is using its associated product price.

I want to use configurable product price instead its simple product price as it is working on magento1 website.

Can any one explain that how configurable product price works ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you want configurable product price. coz the configurable product is not a physical product at all, so magento display it's first child product's price in product detail page.

can explain why you want configurable product's price ?

Comment: I have a configurable product with its price 40$. It is showing in listing page and product detail page $40 which is fine. When I select the options it showing it's simple product price and carry associated simple product price to cart and checkout. I want to use configurable product price as I have already use in magento 1

Comment: you can  not do that and you do not do that. because you are selling the associated simple products, not the configurable product. configurable product is not exist physically.  Magento processing orders with simple product, not with configurable product, even if you go and see the order items tables or quote item table, you will see the simple products.

Comment: you are right. M2 manage the two row for configurable table in order item table as it already use same scenerio in magneto1. As I know, Magento 1 does not use the associated product price